# Using Windows LAN authentication in a VB 6 form

Tags: vb6, ldap, windows-authentication

Can some one please help me in using the lan user id and password to be used in my VB 6 form? I want the user to key in his/her lan uid and password to log in to my VB 6 desktp applicationm. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/279815

Comment: jac, your link doesn't address the OP's question about how to get the user to enter a LAN UID and password into a VB6 form.

Answer (score -1):

Of course it's possible.  Put two text boxes on a form.  Label one of them User ID and the other one Password.  Set the Passwordchar property on the second one to *.  Then, add a submit and a cancel button.  When the user clicks the submit button, add code to look up the user id and password in your database.  If not found, don't let the user in.  If the user tries three times without success, shut down the form.

Comment: I missed the "LAN UID" part of the question.  My bad.  Probably because I've never run across anyone who wanted to get the user to re-enter his LAN UID into an application before.